# How to repeat same FAB button on multiple pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am building an ionic app and want to display a round '+' button in the bottom right corner of most of my pages. clicking this button should take the user to a new page.

but i am unsure how to display the fab button on many pages without duplicating the code again and again....

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared component which you can place it in app.component.html by position absolute to Bottom. When we click the Fab button, you need to emit an observable event to the parent component using Behavior Subject and handle it in your parent components.